# issues after remove of # from URL

Tags: jquery, angularjs, url, redirect

My URL was like https://localhost/admin#/dashboard
so i have to remove # from URL.
i was facing problem to hide # from URL in angularJS, so i have modify my code to resolve this problem as mention on different forums.
i have add

$locationProvider.html5Mode({
   enabled: true,
   requireBase: false
});

and in my index, i have add

```
<base href="/admin">
```

and this my my .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|satellizer|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

it works fine but with 2 problems
it had hide 'admin' from URL and where ever i have used jquery for window.location.href it show me different URL and then suddenly it redirect to new URL without # and admin

Comment: You did set `requireBase: false`. But, used `<base href="/admin">`. why?

Comment: because it only works fine when i set it as i mention, do you have better suggestions please do share with me.

Comment: now i use default for requireBase which is true still it showing me an error.

Comment: What error you exactly facing?

Comment: my current URL like this http://localhost/admin#/pet_owners
i want to remove # from URL and i follow all steps to remove # from url from angular documentation...
after following instructions my url are like this http://localhost/pet_owners but i need admin as well in URL's

Comment: Place that `admin` in your route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove `#` from url make `html5Mode(true)`.

In .config do this:

`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

In head tag placebase tag:

`<base href="/">`

Remove `#` from your anchoring elements().

Don't forget to inject `$locationProvider`.

Comment: thanks i have followed your instructions but 
my index URL like 
'http://localhost/dashboard' 
after click on any anchor tag to open new page its like
'http://localhost/dashboard#%2Fpet_owners'

Comment: Don't place `#` in your anchoring elements. Remove those.